# how can i integrate nexmo SMS account verification with API on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, sms, vonage

I get an API from Nexmo and a want to integrate them on my woocommerce website ,i mean that's. want to send SMS for account verification after registration. I had used this code
 `unction mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id ) {

$mobile="123456";

$url="****/api.php?username=******&password=1234&source=UPDATE&dmobile=".$mobile."&message='.$msg.' ";

$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
//print_r($response);

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing' );`,but i don't think that what want exactly.
please can help me .

Answer (score 0):

For account verification you can use the [Verify API](https://developer.nexmo.com/verify/overview) which already does what you need. There are PHP-specific examples available under "building blocks".

If you do want to send SMS yourself then I recommend you check out the developer documentation for SMS API, it's here: https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/building-blocks/send-an-sms/php.

If you get stuck working through the resources, try asking a more specific question and I or others might be able to help further.

Comment: Ok , i know that i should use an API  code , but the question is when can i  put the code in wordpress and which  file ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any wordpress-specific examples for you, the PHP examples for Nexmo should work for wordpress but I couldn't say where they should be placed for your use case.

Comment: This article could be helpful: https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2019/10/09/adding-2-factor-authentication-to-wordpress-with-nexmo-verify-api-dr